# Changing hyphens (-) to underscores (_) on Win10 for many files: Windows search hack

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, regex, rename, batch-rename

I have a directory with various files and some of the filenames have subparts separated with hyphens / dashes i.e. - e.g. `foo-bar.pdf`

Unfortunately this seems to confuse Windows 10 Explorer's search. e.g. a search string `name:(foo bar)` does NOT seem to find a file named `foo-bar.pdf` However it DOES indeed find the same file if I rename it with underscores as `foo_bar.pdf` (If someone sees different behavior I would love to know! )

Hence I would like to rename all files with dashes / hyphens by changing them to underscores. What would be a good way to first filter out a list of such files and then to rename them?

e.g. In Linux I would have written a shell script or one liner using a Regex and `mv, grep sed, awk` etc.

Any quick ways of doing this on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

For cmd/command line use `ren/rename` in `for` loop and substring replace `variable:-=_"`:

- `// in bat ::`

```bat
for %%i in (*-*.*)do set "_name=%%~ni" && cmd/v/c "ren "%%~i" "!_name:-=_!%%~xi""
```

---

- `// in cmd command line ::`

```bat
for %i in (*-*.*)do set "_name=%~ni" && cmd/v/c "ren "%~i" "!_name:-=_!%~xi""
```

---

- `// in PowerShell ::`

```bat
ls *.pdf| ren -new {$_.basename.replace('-','_')+$_.extension}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. With Poweshell**

You can try using the following command in Powershell:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -Replace '-','_'}
```

It lists the file in the directory, then rename the files by replacing `-` with `_`.

**2. With PowerRename**

You can also do it with PowerRename that comes with [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases). Open PowerToys settings, make sure that PowerRename is enabled and integrated to the shell.

[image: IMG:]

Select the files, right-click and click PowerRename. A widow will be displayed. Enter the criteria to search for `-` and the string to replace it with `-`. Optionally, select Use Regular Expressions. The Preview will show the files' new names. Click OK to rename them.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Since searching for how to do this in linux brought me to this page, I will just leave this here for anyone else in the same situation.

```
for f in *.py; do mv "$f" "${f//-/_}"; done
```